# Looking for method to restore distorted checkerboard image

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

In following image, having detected all corners, I want to determine how I can move each corner to restore it to a undistorted checkerboard while minimizing the total distance of the moves. Any suggestions?

[image: A distorted chaser board image.]

Answer (score 0):

One reliable way - use OpenCV library, learn algorithms used there for [camera calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html), and apply them

[image]